# How to set Blasorise.DataGrid cell's forecolor at run-time?

Tags: blazor, runtime, blazorise

How to set [Blazorise.DataGrid](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/getting-started) cell's forecolor at run-time?
I wanted the forecolor of the sample weather forecast app's **Temp.C.** cells to be set depending on their values, for example,

- if a value is less than Zero - then the color should be set to **Blue**;
- if a value is between zero and 19 - then the color should be set to **Orange**;
- else  - the color should be set to **Red**;

```html
    @page "/fetchdata"

    <PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

    @using BlazoriseDemo.Data
    @using Blazorise;

    @inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

    <h1>Weather forecast</h1>

    <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

    @if (forecasts == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {

        <DataGrid TItem="WeatherForecast"
              Data="@forecasts"
              @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedForecast"
              Responsive>
    
              <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.Date)" Caption="Date"/>
              <DataGridNumericColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureC)" Caption="C" />
              <DataGridNumericColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureF)" Caption="F" />
              <DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(WeatherForecast.Summary)" Caption="Summary"/>

        </DataGrid>

    }

    @code {
        private WeatherForecast selectedForecast;
        private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

        protected string getTempCForegroundColor(int temperatureC)
        {
            var color = "blue";
            if (temperatureC >= 0 && temperatureC < 20) color = "orange";
            else if (temperatureC > 20) color = "red";
            return color;
        }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            forecasts = await new WeatherForecastService().GetForecastAsync(new DateTime(2022,07,1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple solutions:

- use CellStyle attribute of DataGridColumn to set the inline style regarding the row.

ex.

```
<DataGridColumn CellStyle="@((item)=> {if(item.TemperatureC > 19){return "color: #f00";} else { return "color: #00f";}})" [...] />
```

(but using inline style is often a bad practice)

- use CellClass attribute of DataGridColumn to set an utility class to the cell regarding the row.

ex.

```
<DataGridColumn CellClass="@((item)=> {if(item.TemperatureC > 19){return "color-hot";} else { return "color-cold";}})" [...] />
```

and then you have a .css for utility classes (color-hot will set the color to red), quite like bootstrap

- use DisplayTemplate to customize the content of the cell, where you can use the "context" variable that represent current row item:

```
<DataGridColumn [...]>
    <DisplayTemplate>
        <span class="(@context.TemperatureC > 19 ? "color-hot" : "color-cold")">
            @context.TemperatureC
        </span>
    </DisplayTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you! I suppose, I will have to use the CellStyle attribute because the forecolor of a cell value have to be set dynamically on run-time based on the set of temperature ranges wit each of them corresponding to a certain forecolor and this correspondence is defined in program settings (and can be changed on run-time).